Notation of bilinear form with bivariate function
Is there a clean abbreviation/notation of the Fourier transform
$$ \sum_{\boldsymbol{k}, \boldsymbol{k'}} f(k,k') v_\boldsymbol{k} {w}_{\boldsymbol{k'}} e^{i (\boldsymbol{k}+\boldsymbol{k'})\cdot \boldsymbol{x}}
$$
in configuration space?
Here, we defined $k:=|\boldsymbol{k}|$, $k':=|\boldsymbol{k'}|$ and the bivariate function $f(k,k')$.
Evidently it should be a bilinear form, as e.g. $B(v,w)$, but how can you bring in the bivariate functional relationship?
